# Pop up is not opening after Rebinding the DataGrid

Tags: wpf

I have started to work on WPF recently. Currently I am facing an issue.
I have a window , inside that i have an user control which Contains DataGrid, Combobox ,Buttons and a Pop Up.
I am binding DataGrid with List of Notes(string) with Delete Buttons.So when we click on that Button, the pop up will open and Pop up has confirmation message with Yes or No button.
When i click the Yes button i am deleting the Note and Rebinding only the DataGrid.And after that when i click on the Delete Button the pop up is not opening.

If I dont Rebind the DataGrid, in that case PopUp is opening but the problem is deleted Note is still there in the DataGrid though that is deleted from the database, which make confusion whether the Note is deleted or not. That is why I am rebinding.

But Rebinding cause the issue of not opening Popup.

Please help me out how can i get this done.

My Pop up looks like this:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popupdelete"                                        
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           HorizontalOffset="-10" 
           VerticalOffset="10"
           Placement="Mouse"
           StaysOpen="False"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsDeletePopUpOpen}">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="105">
                <!-- My confirmation message and Yes No button goes Here-->
        </Grid>
```

IsDeletePopUpOpen is set in the ViewModel.

Thanks & Regards,
Joy

Comment: You need to post more code atleast one where we can replicate issue as explained by you.

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T> to hold your ItemsSource and the UI will be notified when you remove an item from the collection. Then you don't need to rebind the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Code goes here:

<-- Delete Pop Up-->

```
  <Popup x:Name="Popupdelete"                                        
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           HorizontalOffset="-10" 
           VerticalOffset="10"
           Placement="Mouse"
           StaysOpen="False"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsDeletePopUpOpen}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="105">
            <Border BorderBrush="#E2E2E2" BorderThickness="6" Background="White">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,10,10,50" Foreground="#454545" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="Auto" Text="Are you sure you want" />
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="50,15,50,25" Foreground="#454545" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="Auto" Text="to delete?"/>
                    <Button Content="Yes"  Margin="35,50,80,0" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DeleteYesCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstCustomer}"  Style="{StaticResource SaveButtonStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="or" Margin="75,50,60,15"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#919191" FontSize="10"  />
                    <TextBlock  Margin="95,48,35,12"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ><Hyperlink  Command="{Binding DeleteNoCmd}"><Run Text="No"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"/></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
   </Popup>
```

<--List Of Notes with Delete Image Button-->

```
                            <Border Background="#F0F0F0" CornerRadius="0"  Visibility="{Binding NotesListViewVisibility}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollMe" CanContentScroll="True" Height="80" >
                                    <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5">
                                        <Grid Background="White" Margin="5">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ListView x:Name="lstCustomer"  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" RequestBringIntoView="RemoveScrollViewFocus" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OutcomeNotesView , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionMode="Single"  
                    Background="#FFFFFF" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListviewItemContainerStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <UC:NoteStackPanel/>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <Border BorderBrush="#E6E6E6" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" 
                                                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource widthconv}, ElementName=lstCustomer}">
                                                                <StackPanel x:Name="spNotes"  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                            <Button x:Name="btnPrimaryOfficer" MouseEnter="SetEmployeePopUpPlacement" Style="{StaticResource AuthButton}"
                                                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.OutcomeEmployeePopUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
                                                                                <Button.Visibility>
                                                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActiveInactiveConv}" ConverterParameter="Hyper">
                                                                                        <Binding Path="EmployeeInfo.ActiveStatusCode"/>
                                                                                        <Binding Path="EmployeeInfo.Id"/>
                                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                                </Button.Visibility>
                                                                                <Button.InputBindings>
                                                                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.OutcomeEmployeePopUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                                                                                </Button.InputBindings>
                                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                                    <Image Source="{StaticResource imgUser}" Width="15" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeInfo.Name}"  Style="{StaticResource AuthEditProfile}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontBold}" FontSize="12" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                                            </Button>
                                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                                                                <StackPanel.Visibility>
                                                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ActiveInactiveConv}" ConverterParameter="Normal">
                                                                                        <Binding Path="EmployeeInfo.ActiveStatusCode"/>
                                                                                        <Binding Path="EmployeeInfo.Id"/>
                                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                                </StackPanel.Visibility>
                                                                                <!--Visibility="{Binding PrimaryOfficerActiveStatusCode,Converter={StaticResource ActiveInactiveConv},ConverterParameter=Normal}">-->
                                                                                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgUserBlack}" Width="15" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding EmployeeInfo.Name}" Style="{StaticResource TextWithoutHyperlink}" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                                            <TextBlock Background="Transparent"  Text="on" 
                                                                             FontFamily="{StaticResource FontMedium}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#919191" Margin="4,0,2,0" 
                                                                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AddedDate, StringFormat=\{0:MM/dd/yy\}}" Foreground="#454545" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  MaxLength="{Binding Length}"
                                                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ContentText}"/>
                                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.DeleteNoteVisibility, ElementName=OutcomeNotesView}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                                                                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Width="Auto" MouseEnter="btnDelete_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnDelete_MouseLeave"
                                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.LoadDeletePopUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                                                           Style="{StaticResource AuthButton}">
                                                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                                        <Image Source="{StaticResource imgdeleteicon}" Style="{StaticResource AuthImage}"/>
                                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                                </Button>
                                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                    <StackPanel >
                                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Note}" Foreground="#454545" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" 
                                                                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource widthconv}, ElementName=lstCustomer}"
                                                                 Style="{StaticResource ContentText}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontNormal}" FontSize="12" Padding="0"/>
                                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtSavingNoteId" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{Binding NoteId}" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ListView>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
```

```
    public List<ActivityNotesDto> OutcomeNotesView
    {
        get
        {
            return outcomeNotesView;
        }
        set
        {
            outcomeNotesView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutcomeNotesView");
        }
    }
```

DeleteActivityNote(deletingNoteDetails);

OutcomeNotesView = GetActivityNotesList();

Please let me know if i am missing something.Since first time when i click button Delete popup is opening and it is deleting but next time when i click on the Delete image it didnt open the pop up.

Thanks & Regards,
Joy